# Several versions of Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

For reasons related to customers with different applications versions i need to maintain in my laptop several versions of Delphi (7, XE 7, XE 8, XE 10.1 Berlin and XE 10.2 Tokyo). My main concern is about PATH variable and problems during compilation and linking time. There'll be any problems ? Do i need to change what ? Any suggestion is  most welcome.

Comment: I have 7 and XE8 on the same machine without problems. Don't know of different XE versions could give problems. But there is always VMWare for this

Comment: Remove all references to Delphi from your PATH environment variable. This is how I work. I have many Delphi versions installed. When I need a command line build environment, I use `rsvars.bat` for the appropriate version. This sets up the necessary environment.

Comment: Maybe PATH variable will be so long with all those versions that you will have some compilation problems. PATH variable has a limited number of characters.

Comment: Create batch files for every Version and clean up your path. In your Batch-File adjust the Path and start the Delphi Version

Comment: Ok, so i need to create a batch file for each version to set it's own PATH variable. Where can i find info about each version and how do i restore PATH variable after using Delphi to it's original value ?

Comment: Don't need to restore anything. Remove all references to Delphi from your environment. Then execute rsvars.bat and it's all good.

Comment: I have RAD Studio XE7, XE8, and 10 Seattle all installed, and everything works perfect - EXCEPT for one single third-party library, which was horribly designed, and even having two separate copies of said library, it only works in one. Won't let me build for more than one version. But that's just one library, which I intend to rid anyway. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Short filenames is the solution to PATH too long problem.

Comment: @Free What's the solution to finding a specific version of dcc32? That issue means that as soon as you have multiple delphi versions, you have to have bespoke environments and thus it is pointless to have multiple installed versions referenced in the system path.

Comment: When Delphi installs it adds to the environment path (command prompt "set path"), so it's easy to copy that out to a batch file. For each version of Delphi have a different batch file (as stated above). Remove all references to Delphi stuff from the environment path. Use subst command to avoid long paths. Run the version-specific batch file before launching any Delphi version. Maintain your batch files when installing 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have all versions of Delphi from 7 thru XE8 installed in a single VM and versions 1 thru 6 in another (my Delphi "museum" :)).

The Delphi "museum" is a **Windows XP** VM to avoid the problems that those older versions of Delphi have with more recent Windows versions.  The Delphi 7+ VM started life as **Windows 7** VM but has since been upgraded to **Windows 8.x** and then **Windows 10** without any problem.

The two sets of VM's are kept separate in this way to avoid OS complications with those older versions and because I use 1-6 only very, *very* rarely and version 7+ more often.  The precise version at which the "cut-off" was made was determined by the fact that dotted unit names were also only supported from version 7 onward so a lot of the code I ever wrote for 7+ is simply not even usable with 1-6 so there's no point having them alongside each other.

In both cases the IDE/compilers (any version) have no intrinsic problems running alongside other versions.

The only real difficulty is installing **Delphi 2006** on **Windows Vista** (or later).  Should you ever need to, this is the only one that presents any real difficulty due to a dependency on .NET which is not handled very well by the installer.  But it is do-able and not especially difficult as long as you follow [the steps described in detail by Dr. Bob](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin84.htm).

### Install Locations: Minimising PATH Length/Manageability

With a large number of Delphi versions installed the overall length of the PATH variable can become a problem, but in my experience this is a problem only of manageability.  To simplify things on that score and to avoid problems with earlier versions of Delphi on more recent versions of Windows, I installed all my IDE's in a sub-folder directly off the root:

```
c:\delphi\<version>
```

Where `version` is each Delphi version number (e.g. 7.0, 2007, 2009, XE, XE2 etc etc).  I then have a number of other folders for shared components:

```
c:\delphi\bde
c:\delphi\database desktop
c:\delphi\shared files
```

When I setup the VM I installed each Delphi version in order and changed the installation locations for these components to these locations.  In this way there is one common installation of these shared components which is updated by each more recent version as required.

I also have a `c:\delphi\common\` folder where I keep things such as pre-compiled **FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll** etc to be shared across all Delphi versions.

I did all this primarily for my own benefit however, to keep things organised and consistent rather than to solve any particular problem (apart from the previously mentioned issues affecting older versions if installed under **Program Files**).

e.g. if you simply install into default locations then you will end up with versions "scattered" across Borland, CodeGear and Embarcadero folders.  All my IDE versions are in one place.

With or without these considerations, the IDE should be perfectly happy to run all the different versions you mention without any particular configuration required, but you may need to pay attention to configuration/assumptions made by some 3rd party packages/libraries.

### 3rd Party Packages

Most 3rd party libraries/packages are usually fine, but there may be the occasional one that needs a bit of help.  I myself have never come across anything that couldn't be resolved but have to say that I also don't use 3rd party libraries particularly extensively so simply may not have come across any "trouble makers".

In any event, it's unfortunately difficult to give general advice on this point since it obviously depends very much on the 3rd party libraries and the particular "problems" that any particular one might have.

Answer (score 2):

I have all Delphi versions from 6 to 10.2 installed on a computer running Windows 8.1 64 bit. It's not easy to setup, especially for the older versions. The first rule would be: Do not install to "c:\program files", use a separate directory (I use "c:\delphi" with a numerical subdirectory for each version.)
That has two effects:

- Older versions, that still write to the installation directory, will work.
- The path entries will not be as long (even though, they will be too long after the 5th or 6th Delphi install, see the comments to your question for possible solutions)

Why did I not use multiple VMs? I maintain GExperts for the versions mentioned above and it is too much hassle to maintain the VMs. As long as it works, I will keep all Delphi versions on my computer. If it stops working, I will probably drop GExperts suppport for some Delphi versions.

There are multiple articles on getting older Delphi versions to work on Windows 8.1. They might be useful if you try it.
They are all in the category Windows 8.1:

https://blog.dummzeuch.de/category/windows/windows-8-1/